# When I run cypress autotests as a list, some of them crash

Tags: cypress

I updated Cypress from the 10 version to the 12 version.
I have 30-40 autotests and set them there in one autotest 'test-in-order.cy.js':

```
import './1_test.cy';
...
import './40_test.cy';
```

And launch the test test-in-order.cy.js.

```
  │ Tests:        40   
  │ Passing:      24
  │ Failing:      16
```

But when I launch each autotest separately, All autotests were passed.
What can I do?

Cypress.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  video: true,
  viewportWidth: 1920,
  viewportHeight: 1024,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  defaultTimeout: 30000,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 40000,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  responseTimeout: 60000,
  timeout: 60000,
  e2e: {
      setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config);
    },
baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000'
  }
});
```

Environment:

```
MacOS: Ventura 13.3.1.
Chip: Apple M1
Memory: 16Gb
```